# get_file_content not working for https

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I am using php and google's new [CSE](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) in my website . The URL for request is like
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures

The connection is https and file_get_content() is getting failed. How can i get it working?
Since i need to host the site on some external web-hosting servers, I am in need of solution which don't alter php configuration file or work with default options found on most of web-hosting sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `curl`:

```
## HTTPS url that you are targeting.
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.23 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

## Below two option will enable the HTTPS option.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` are necessary if I dont have any certificate?

Comment: The server he is accessing (googleapis.com) has a certificate, not his machine running the script. The server certificate needs to be validated in order to initialize the secure connection.

Comment: While I have no trouble with the suggestion of using curl, the statement _"You can't read a webpage over https using file_get_contents()."_ is utterly, utterly false. Downvoting because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. `file_get_contents` works with registered stream wrappers ( http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php ) and even though `ssl` is not by default in the list, it can be configured using the openssl extension as someone suggested (necessary at least for windows).

Comment: @mazzucci Do wrapper works for ssl too. I cant find any mention of https in the mannaul.

Comment: I think curl is the best way to go. It should be configured on most of the servers. I request you to edit the answer before I accept it as pointed by @Wrikken.

Comment: Is it necessary to use  CURLOPT_USERAGENT ? b'coz it is working without it.

Comment: I edited the answer as suggested. The CURLOPT_USERAGENT is optional

Comment: Aight, `file_get_contents` thingamayig gone, downvote gone ;)

Comment: @Wrikken Sorry, what is the downvote for? I accepted your notice, I added additional information about the stream wrappers, I corrected my answer as the edit was suggested, what is the issue?

Comment: I am stating the downvote from yesterday is _gone_ because the incorrect information is _gone_.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the config yourself, talk to the hosting provider. It most probably has to do with the lacking of openssl in the php core or startup.

If you are doing this for someone else and you have no control or contact with the host (the "some external host"), explain the situation and help them find a suitable host with the appropriate features enabled.